# phpMyAdmin how do I use the search for multiple values?

Tags: phpmyadmin

I feel like I'm missing something really obvious.

[image: phpMyAdmin Search]

I can't see how to search for several values (using either AND or OR) in a column using phpMyAdmin (version 4.1.14) without typing out a full sql query?

Comment: Check the "options" sections.

Comment: Nothing in there related to this :(

Comment: Why not just use a regular query?

Comment: That involved having to think ;)